# Question on Convergence in Probability

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, asymptotics

I appreciate if you could guide me on this question:

Assumptions:

- $X_n \rightarrow^p c$: $X_n$ convrges in probability to a constant c.
- g(.) is any function that satisfies: 
  $$\text{if } a_n - c = o(1) \text{ then } g(a_n) - g(c) = o(1)$$

I need to show:

$$g(X_n) - g(c) = o_p(1)$$

Thank you for guiding me on this question.

---

Here is my solution so far:

Consider this theorem: $X_n \rightarrow^p X$ if and only if every subsequence $n_1, n_2, \dots \in \{1,2, 3, \dots\}$, has a sub-subsequence $m_1, m_2, \dots \in \{n_1, n_2, ...\}$ such that $X_{m_j}\rightarrow^{a.s.} X$ where a.s. stands for almost surely.

Now, since $X_n \rightarrow^p c$, then by theorem above, there exists a subsequence $X_{m_j}$ for which $X_{m_j} \rightarrow^{a.s} c$ and therefore we can write (I'm not sure about this part):

$$ X_{m_j} - c = o(1)$$

Therefore, based on the definition of g(.), we can write:
$$ g(X_{m_j}) - g(c) = o(1)$$

And this means that we have sub-subsequence of $g(X_n)$ that converges almost surely to g(c) so then by the theorem above we can conclude:

$$ g(X_{n}) \rightarrow^p g(c)$$

and this can be written as:

$$ g(X_{n}) - g(c) = o_p(1)$$

What do you think about my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that $|X_n-c|>\epsilon$ has probability converging to 0. You want the same for $|g(X_n)-g(c)|>\delta$.

Suppose you take $b<c<d$. Choose them so that $|g(x)-g(c)|<\delta$ for $b<x<d$. Now evaluate the probability that $X_n$ is not in this range.

---

*In response to your solution:* You're right about the point which is shaky. The problem is that $X_m-c=o(1)$ doesn't mean anything, because $o(1)$ is a statement about analytic limits, but the left-hand side is a random variable.

You don't need to do anything complicated, that was the point I was driving at. You've observed that
$$X_n \to^p c \iff X_n - c = o_p(1) \iff \forall \epsilon>0: \lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb P(|X_n - c| > \epsilon) = 0$$
Now you choose an interval $(b,d)\ni c$ such that $|g(x) - g(c)| < \delta$ for any normal, real number $x\in(b,d)$. This is the only place you need an $o(1)$-type argument. Hence
$$\mathbb P(|g(X_n) - g(c)| > \delta) \quad<\quad \mathbb P(X_n \text{ not in } (b,d))$$
But now you know that the right-hand side (which is just a number now, not a random variable or anything) tends to 0 as $n\to\infty$, from the above statement.

Hence the LHS tends to zero. But this is the definition of $g(X_n)\to^p c$.

Comment: Hi @Sharkos, by x you mean $X_n$ ?

Comment: I mean the "the probability that b<x<d does not hold if we set $x=X_n$" if you prefer that, yes. There is nothing random about the sentence before this though, there $x$ is just a number. You should be able to relate this to the opening observation.

Comment: exactly, my guess is the most import part is to know how to make a bridge between $o_p(1)$ and $o(1)$. I'm going to edit my question and add my solution so far. I appreciate if you give me some feedback about it. I'll then try to work on your idea. Thanks

Comment: Just finished writing my solution ...

Comment: Cool...Thanks a lot